# Testing reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: javascript, php, bots, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to add Google reCAPTCHA v3 to a website but first I wanted to test it on a simple form.

I added the necessary JS and php to send the request and handle the response in the back-end. When I submit a form manually I get a score of 0.9 which is good, but I've come across people that always got a score of 0.9 whether it was human or bot.

So is there a way to check if it actually works and not just always returns the same score?

I did some research and found that you can change the user agent to Googlebot/2.1 or using incognito mode but neither of them worked (still got a score of 0.9). I even tried to scrape the form and submit it using a python script but it didn't work.

Do you have any suggestions on how to test if it actually works?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refresh the form submit, it usually get a worse score.

Also think that if scores 0.9 means that recaptcha works fine and you have the response so it should work fine!